# Where do cloud solution/API questions go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was recently wanting to ask a question along the lines of "What options do I have for recurring billing in my web application?"

Where would a question like this go?

Comment: Yahoo! Answers, Quora, reddit/r/programming, Hacker News...

Comment: ...also worth noting that the [API Finder Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36863/api-finder) was closed... [Shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) don't really work on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question would go into the bin as a shopping receipt across the network.

If you had a question about how to use (or not have horribly fall apart on you) of a particular feature of a host then that would be an acceptable and constructive form of the question. In that case it would fall under [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) if you were a consumer.

If you were a developer and wanted to extend something of the host, that might be either [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).